# What purpose does .astype("uint8") have here?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, ssim

```
(score,diff)= structural_similarity(original_gray,tempered_gray,full=True)

diff = (diff*255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM:{}".format(score))
```

The above mentioned code is a snippet from a program that matches two images using their SSIM score. What I don't understand here is the function of `.astype("uint8")`,  and why are we multiplying `diff` by 255?

Comment: It converts whatever you give it to a 8 bit integer (from 0 to 255) by a modulo 256 operation. Because 255 and -1 are congruent modulo 256, it is kinda equivalent to taking the "symmetrical" of that number in the range 0-255 (0 returns 0, 1 returns 255, 2 returns 254...). Why? Nobody can tell you without context

Comment: @MateoVial I think it's more likely that the original range is 0.0-1.0 and they want to convert it to 0-255.

Comment: Indeed, i didn't think of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a 2D array representing a greyscale (single channel) image. In general, the image data can come at you in one of two ways:

1. Pixel values are floats ranging from 0 to 1, or...
2. Pixel values are integers ranging from 0 to 255.

Occasionally you might also see levels expressed as percentages between 0 and 100, but that's basically the same as (1) above. Note that (2) can only express 255 grey levels, whereas (1) has almost arbitrary precision.

Sometimes you need (1) but have (2), or vice versa. Because software or preference or whatever.

To convert from (1) to (2) you must multiply by 255 and ensure that you have integers. In order to use the least amount of memory, you only need 8-bit integers, but those come in two flavours: signed (`int8`, ranging -128 to +127) and unsigned (`uint8`, ranging 0 to 255). For images you always want the unsigned kind.

To convert from (2) to (1) you can just divide by 255, making sure the result can hold floating point numbers of the desired precision.

So in your code, `diff` is being converted from a floating point image to an 8-bit one.

Comment: It's better to multiply by 255.999 than 255, to even out the distribution of final values. If you don't, 0.999999 will map to 254 which isn't optimal.

Comment: Hm... interesting point, but I'm not so sure. Maybe that's what you want... At some point you just have to make a decision about how you want to round things, depending on the distribution of your data. Like, you could also have values in a half-open interval, eg from `np.random.random()`.

Comment: Your example with random numbers is perfect for illustrating the problem I'm trying to avoid. Chances are your result won't have a single pixel with a value of 255 because the final band is too small while every other value will be evenly distributed.